# Initializing a database on the first run

Tags: android, database, sqlite, initialization

I'd like to initialize the app database when user starts the app for the first time.

My first idea was to add a db file in assets and copy it to app db directory.
But it doesn't seem to be possible.

So, my new idea is to code all the insert statements in a specific method. But I can't find how to export the whole actual database into insert statements.

I use DB Navigator and the best I found was export into csv, table after table.

I can't believe there's no better and simpler way...

Comment: "My first idea was to add a db file in assets and copy it to app db directory. But it doesn't seem to be possible" -- sure it is. While [`SQLiteAssetHelper` is no longer actively maintained](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), AFAIK it still works, and there may be replacements around.

Comment: You're right. Thanks to your link, I have been able to copy the reference db file from assets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CommonsWare and SQLiteAssetHelper, here's a simplified code to copy a db file from assets to application.

```
   //in a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper
   public void importDefault() throws Exception {

        String assetPath = "db/myApp.default.db";
        String deviceDbDirectory;
        InputStream is;

        is = contexte.getAssets().open(assetPath);
        deviceDbDirectory = getWritableDatabase().getPath();
        writeExtractedFileToDisk(is, new FileOutputStream(deviceDbDirectory));
    }


    private void writeExtractedFileToDisk(InputStream in, OutputStream outs) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
            outs.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outs.flush();
        outs.close();
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: This will not work, without modification, for Android Pie+. See answer that explains why and potential modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer that suggests using :-

```
//in a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper
   public void importDefault() throws Exception {

        String assetPath = "db/myApp.default.db";
        String deviceDbDirectory;
        InputStream is;

        is = contexte.getAssets().open(assetPath);
        deviceDbDirectory = getWritableDatabase().getPath();
        writeExtractedFileToDisk(is, new FileOutputStream(deviceDbDirectory));
    }


    private void writeExtractedFileToDisk(InputStream in, OutputStream outs) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
            outs.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        outs.flush();
        outs.close();
        in.close();
    }
```

May work for pre Android Pie where the default **journal** mode is used. It will not work, without modification for Android Pie+ where the default is to use **WAL** (**W**rite-**A**head **L**ogging).

The reason being that the getWritableDatabase, does that, it gets (opens) the database, which in WAL mode results in the -shm and -wal files being generated and populated.

As the data in the files is not committed when the copied database is opened the first open after the copy open detects that the -wal and -shm do not belong to the copied database (instead they belong to the empty database). The result is that the opened database is a new empty database (due to the corruption and how the open tries to return a usable database).

## Fixes

There are a number of fixes.

One is to override the **onConfigure** method and use the SQLiteDatabase **db.disableWriteAheadLogging();** method to use journal mode. e.g. :-

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
}
```

- The App then does not take advantage of advantages offered by WAL and is therefore not recommended.

Another is to ensure that the outstanding transactions are committed, this can be achieved by closing the database before the copy is undertaken. e.g. by using :-

```
public void importDefault() throws Exception {

    String assetPath = "db/myApp.default.db";
    String deviceDbDirectory;
    SQLiteDatabase crtdirdb;
    InputStream is;

    is = contexte.getAssets().open(assetPath);
    deviceDbDirectory = (crtdirdb = getWritableDatabase()).getPath(); //CHANGED TO GET THE SQLITE DATABASE OBJECT
    crtdirdb.close(); //ADDED TO CLOSE THE DATABASE AND THUS COMMIT TRANSACTIONS

    writeExtractedFileToDisk(is, new FileOutputStream(deviceDbDirectory));
}
```

- This has the advantage that it will work with pre as well as Android Pie+ maintaining the default or specified logging mode.
- However like any method that utilises **getWritableDatabase** or **getReadableDatabase** (it doesn't matter which as the latter will get the former most of the time) it is relatively resource hungry and as such is not recommended due to it's in efficiency.

Another fix woukld be to delete the -shm and - wal files, which is effectively dropping the outstanding transactions.

- This is still not recommended as it is still inefficient.

## Why get????Database

**getWritableDatabase** or **getReadableDatabase** appear to have been used historically simply to get around the ENOENT issue that is encountered without.

The ENONENT is because when a new App is installed and then run the data/data/package directory exists but NOT the data/data/package/databases directory and thus the file copy fails because of the missing directory.

The *lazy/easy* get around is the one line to code (but many underlying lines to run) getWritableDatabse. The underlying code has to check to see if the file exists and if it does not check to see if the parent directories exist and if no create them, open the file pas the open file (back) to the SQlite SDK open which then goes through the process of generating the file header, the sqlite_master table and the android_metadata table before completing either managing the -jorunal file or the -wal and -shm files and then returning.

All of this processing is then wasted/undone by overwriting the database with the copy from the assets file.

The efficient way is to check is to utilise the **File** methods to see if the **databases** (not specifically as in theory that could change) directory exists and to create it using the **File**'s **mkdirs** method.

As such the **importDefault** method would be more efficient, work for Android Pie+ and be more future resilient if it were :-

```
public void importDefault() throws Exception {

    String assetPath = "db" + File.separator + dbname;
    InputStream is = contexte.getAssets().open(assetPath);
    File db = contexte.getDatabasePath(dbname);
    if (!db.getParentFile().exists()) {
        db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    writeExtractedFileToDisk(is, new FileOutputStream(db));
}
```

- note **dbname** being set as a class variable for the class.
- The database has the following tables :-

  - [image]
- And the following Triggers :-

  - [image]

As such the complete class that overrides SQLiteOpenHelper could be :-

```
public class DBBasicAssetCopy extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context contexte;
    static String dbname = "myApp.default.db";
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    public DBBasicAssetCopy(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, dbname, null , 1);
        this.contexte = context;
        if (!(new File(contexte.getDatabasePath(dbname).getPath())).exists()) {
            try {
                importDefault();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Error copying Asset");
            }
        }
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /* Could be used as a fix
    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
    */

    public void importDefault() throws Exception {

        String assetPath = "db" + File.separator + dbname; //minimal hard coding
        InputStream is = contexte.getAssets().open(assetPath);
        File db = contexte.getDatabasePath(dbname);
        if (!db.getParentFile().exists()) {
            db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        writeExtractedFileToDisk(is, new FileOutputStream(db));
    }

    private void writeExtractedFileToDisk(InputStream in, OutputStream outs) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        int totalbytes = 0;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
            outs.write(buffer, 0, length);
            totalbytes = totalbytes + length;
        }
        outs.flush();
        outs.close();
        in.close();
        Log.d("WEFTD_TOTAL","The total bytes copied was " + String.valueOf(totalbytes));
    }
}
```

## Another fix

## Example (proof)

using (the db as an asset) :-

[image]

The along with the above **DBBasicAssetCopy** class and using :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //DBAssetHelper mDBhlpr;
    DBBasicAssetCopy mDBHlpr002;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*
        mDBhlpr = new DBAssetHelper(this);
        Cursor csr = mDBhlpr.getWritableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBENTITIES","Name = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name"))
                    + "Type = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type")) +
                    "SQL = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("sql")));
        }
        mDBhlpr.close();
        */

        mDBHlpr002 = new DBBasicAssetCopy(this);
        Cursor csr = mDBHlpr002.getWritableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBENTITIES","Name = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name"))
                    + "Type = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("type")) +
                    "SQL = " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("sql")));
        }

        csr.close();
        mDBHlpr002.close();
    }
}
```

## Run 1

using code (as per the other answer), on an Android 23 API device (emulator). new install, that uses :-

public void importDefault() throws Exception {

```
    String assetPath = "db/myApp.default.db";
    String deviceDbDirectory;
    InputStream is;

    is = contexte.getAssets().open(assetPath);
    deviceDbDirectory = getWritableDatabase().getPath();
    writeExtractedFileToDisk(is, new FileOutputStream(deviceDbDirectory));
}
```

Works (same output as per 3 and 4)

## Run 2 - The ISSUE

using the code as for **Run 1** on an Android 28 API device (emulator). new install :-

```
2019-06-10 12:35:21.566 13285-13285/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/WEFTD_TOTAL: The total bytes copied was 40960
2019-06-10 12:35:21.566 13285-13285/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = android_metadataType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
```

- Yes even though the database was copied (approx 40kB copied) the only table that exists is **android_metadata**.

## Run 3

Run from a new install on an Android API 23 device- (emulator) :-

```
2019-06-10 12:08:23.842 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/WEFTD_TOTAL: The total bytes copied was 40960
2019-06-10 12:08:23.847 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = android_metadataType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.847 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = room_master_tableType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.847 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = EntityTestTableType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE `EntityTestTable` (`_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `booleanPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `charPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `bytePrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `shortPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `intPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `longPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `doublePrimative` REAL NOT NULL, `floatPrimative` REAL NOT NULL, `stringObj` TEXT, `booleanObj` INTEGER, `characterObj` INTEGER, `byteObj` INTEGER, `shortObj` INTEGER, `intObj` INTEGER, `longObj` INTEGER, `floatObj` REAL, `doubleObj` REAL, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`))
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = EVENT_SETTINGSType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE EVENT_SETTINGS (
        DBTS BIGINT NOT NULL,
        DBTS_TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    )
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = CS_EVENT_PRICE_LISTType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST (
        EVENT_PRICE_LIST_ID INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
        SALES_TAX           DECIMAL (8, 2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        TAX_TYPE            INTEGER        DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
        INSERTEDBY          VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
        INSTERTEDON         TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
        UPDATEDBY           VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
        UPDATEDON           TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
        TS                  BIGINT         NOT NULL
    )
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = sqlite_sequenceType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = ti_CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST_standardType = triggerSQL = CREATE TRIGGER ti_CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST_standard BEFORE INSERT ON CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST
    WHEN (SELECT Enabled FROM TriggerControl WHERE TriggerType = 'productTables')
        BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST ( Description, Sales_Tax, Tax_Type, insertedby, instertedon, updatedby, updatedon, ts)
            VALUES (new.Description, new.Sales_Tax, new.Tax_Type,
                    new.insertedby, 
                    COALESCE(new.instertedon, julianday('now')), 
                    COALESCE(new.updatedby, new.insertedby), 
                    COALESCE(new.updatedon, julianday('now')),
                    (select DBTS + 1 from EVENT_SETTINGS where rowid = 1));

        UPDATE EVENT_SETTINGS 
            SET DBTS = (select ts from CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST where Description = new.Description),
                DBTS_TS = julianday('now')
        WHERE rowid = 1;

        SELECT RAISE(IGNORE);
        END
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = TriggerControlType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE TriggerControl (Enabled INTEGER, TriggerType TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = buchungType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE buchung (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,othercolumn TEXT, Datum TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = update_buchungType = triggerSQL = CREATE TRIGGER update_buchung BEFORE UPDATE ON Buchung
    WHEN old.Datum IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

                SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "UPDATE NOT ALLOWED");
    END
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = insert_buchungType = triggerSQL = CREATE TRIGGER insert_buchung AFTER INSERT ON Buchung 
    BEGIN 
        update Buchung SET Datum = datetime('now') WHERE ID = NEW.ID; 
    END
```

## Run 4

run from a new install on and Android 28 device (emulator) :-

```
2019-06-10 12:08:23.842 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/WEFTD_TOTAL: The total bytes copied was 40960
2019-06-10 12:08:23.847 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = android_metadataType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.847 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = room_master_tableType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.847 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = EntityTestTableType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE `EntityTestTable` (`_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `booleanPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `charPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `bytePrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `shortPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `intPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `longPrimative` INTEGER NOT NULL, `doublePrimative` REAL NOT NULL, `floatPrimative` REAL NOT NULL, `stringObj` TEXT, `booleanObj` INTEGER, `characterObj` INTEGER, `byteObj` INTEGER, `shortObj` INTEGER, `intObj` INTEGER, `longObj` INTEGER, `floatObj` REAL, `doubleObj` REAL, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`))
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = EVENT_SETTINGSType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE EVENT_SETTINGS (
        DBTS BIGINT NOT NULL,
        DBTS_TS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    )
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = CS_EVENT_PRICE_LISTType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST (
        EVENT_PRICE_LIST_ID INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
        SALES_TAX           DECIMAL (8, 2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        TAX_TYPE            INTEGER        DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
        INSERTEDBY          VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
        INSTERTEDON         TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
        UPDATEDBY           VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
        UPDATEDON           TIMESTAMP      NOT NULL,
        TS                  BIGINT         NOT NULL
    )
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = sqlite_sequenceType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.848 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = ti_CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST_standardType = triggerSQL = CREATE TRIGGER ti_CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST_standard BEFORE INSERT ON CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST
    WHEN (SELECT Enabled FROM TriggerControl WHERE TriggerType = 'productTables')
        BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST ( Description, Sales_Tax, Tax_Type, insertedby, instertedon, updatedby, updatedon, ts)
            VALUES (new.Description, new.Sales_Tax, new.Tax_Type,
                    new.insertedby, 
                    COALESCE(new.instertedon, julianday('now')), 
                    COALESCE(new.updatedby, new.insertedby), 
                    COALESCE(new.updatedon, julianday('now')),
                    (select DBTS + 1 from EVENT_SETTINGS where rowid = 1));

        UPDATE EVENT_SETTINGS 
            SET DBTS = (select ts from CS_EVENT_PRICE_LIST where Description = new.Description),
                DBTS_TS = julianday('now')
        WHERE rowid = 1;

        SELECT RAISE(IGNORE);
        END
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = TriggerControlType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE TriggerControl (Enabled INTEGER, TriggerType TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = buchungType = tableSQL = CREATE TABLE buchung (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,othercolumn TEXT, Datum TEXT)
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = update_buchungType = triggerSQL = CREATE TRIGGER update_buchung BEFORE UPDATE ON Buchung
    WHEN old.Datum IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

                SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "UPDATE NOT ALLOWED");
    END
2019-06-10 12:08:23.849 12981-12981/aso.sqliteassethelpertest D/DBENTITIES: Name = insert_buchungType = triggerSQL = CREATE TRIGGER insert_buchung AFTER INSERT ON Buchung 
    BEGIN 
        update Buchung SET Datum = datetime('now') WHERE ID = NEW.ID; 
    END
```

## SQLiteAssetHelper, the simple solution

The code above includes commented out lines for using the suggested SQLIteAssethelper which works for both pre and Android Pie+ in which case the far simpler Database Helper is :-

```
public class DBAssetHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mytestdb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public DBAssetHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, null, DBVERSION);
    }
}
```

- note that the commented out testing used the same database file but named **mytestdb** and placed into the assets/databases folder (as SQLiteAssetHelper requires).
- additionally to use the SQLiteAssethelper you need to include the line :-

  - `implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'`
- in the dependencies section of the App's **build.gradle**
- Although not supported it is still a feasible and sound option. If you look at the code it does not use get????Database but uses the File methods to check to see if the database exists and also to create the databases directory if needed.